# What is the difference between an Array and an Observable Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, observable

In TypeScript, what is the main difference between `any[]` and `Observable<any[])>`?
What are the cons and pros of using each of them?

Comment: Well, I think it has to do with if an array is observed or not :).[Observable Arrays can respond to a change in the number of items in the collection (array)](http://www.charlesnurse.com/Blog/Post/445/It-s-a-Knockout-7-Adding-items-to-and-Removing-items-from-Observable-Arrays)

Comment: Observable<any[]> is the object with any[] as template, any[] is just any kind of array

Comment: not to be confused with an [`ObservableArray`](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/#idl-observable-array). Arguably this question is missing a tag, `Observable<T>` is not a typescript nor JavaScript type. It's a type from some 3rd party library and this question should arguably have a tag for that library.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Observables are used for implementing the Observer pattern. You can subscribe this Observable and you are getting asynchrounous noticed when the Observable emits data.

`Observable<any[])` is **Observable** which contains an array. In this case, the array can contain any type, since it is typed by *any*.

An **array** is only an object, which can hold more than one value at a time.

> The Observable object represents a push based collection.
>
> The Observer and Observable interfaces provide a generalized mechanism
>   for push-based notification, also known as the observer design
>   pattern. The Observable object represents the object that sends
>   notifications (the provider); the Observer object represents the class
>   that receives them (the observer).

[Take a look at the rxjs docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html)

*vs.*

> Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations. Neither the length of a JavaScript array nor the types of its elements are fixed.

[MDN - Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: An array is not a "variable", although it could be assigned to one. It's a particular type of value.

Comment: Yes, this description was a  little imprecise. I update my answer.

Comment: Is Observable<any[]> an array of observables, or an *array as an observable* or *an array in an observable*?

Answer (score 11):

For a great overview of various types of values across space and time, both singular and plural, see [A General Theory of Reactivity](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor).

An array is an **spatial iterable**. In other words, it's an iterable (a list of things) which exists at one point in space, and which you can, and want to, consume right now.

An observable is a **temporal iterable**. In other words, it's a list of things spread out over time, which you consume one by one.

To take a concrete example, let's examine how to iterate over each of these types of lists:

**Array**:

```
const array: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
array.forEach(elt => console.log(elt));
```

This is **synchronous** and will execute right now.

**Observable**:

```
const observable: Observable<number> = Observable.from([1, 2, 3]);
observable.subscribe(elt => console.log(elt));
```

This is **asynchronous**, and will execute one element at a time, as they come in.

However, you have asked a slightly different question, which is *the difference between an array and an observable of arrays* (which, for sake of clarity, we should avoid calling an "array observable", since that could be misconstrued as meaning an "array of observables", which is a different thing, although certainly useful).

The difference is that, as I mentioned, an array is just a single list of values at a single point in time. An observable of arrays is a **stream** of arrays, each "tick" yielding a entire, new, different array.

Therefore, use an array if you just want a list of items sitting there. Of course you can mutate or transform the array, but that doesn't change the fact that at any given point in time there is just one single array.

Use an observable of arrays if you intend to continue to get new versions of the array--different versions at different points in time--and you want to "push" each new version out to different parts of your program, which in observable terminology will "subscribe" to the observable, and be notified each time it is updated.

To answer your question then:

> What is the main difference between `any[]` and `Observable<any[])>`?

One is an array, and the other is an observable (stream) of arrays.

> What are the cons and pros of using each of them?

The pros and cons are that if you want an array, you should use an array. If you want an observable of arrays, then you should use an observable of arrays.

Please note that although your question refers to TypeScript, the notions of arrays and observables, including observables of arrays, are essentially language-independent.

Comment: 4 downvotes? WTH? I'm not sure whether this answer is good, because the question is horrible, but it certainly isn't that bad.

Comment: @Bergi The downvotes came from an earlier, snarky version of the answer, see edit history.

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user663031 What was snarky about the previous versions?

Comment: AFAICT there is no such thing as `Observable<T>` in typescript. Are you referring to some 3rd party library?