# How to subscribe to an array of observables?

Tags: angular

I would like to subscribe to an array of Observables and get a notification whenever any of the Observables completes.

I know I can use `forkJoin` to see when they all complete but I can't seem to find a way to subscribe without looping through and subscribing to each one individually.

My observable array looks like this:

```
subscriptions: Observable<Dwsubscriptionresponse>[] = [];
```

Comment: Can u please share the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a type `Observable<any>[]` which is an array of observable, you might want to use `Observable<any[]>` which is an observable with an array value.

I would redirect you to this question: [What is the difference between an Array and an Observable Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645190/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-observable-array)